# The proof that if $a_{1}>1$ and $a_{n+1}=2-\frac{1}{a_{n}}$ for $n\geq 1$, then $\{a_{n}\}$ is monotone

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am trying to make a proof that $\{a_{n}\}$ is monotone if

> $$a_{1}>1\;\; \text{and}\;\; a_{n+1}=2-\frac{1}{a_{n}} \;\;\text{for}\;\; n\geq 1$$

Here is what I've done!

> Let $a_{1}>1$ then $\frac{1}{a_{1}}<1$

Base case: When $n=1$

> $$a_{2}=2-\frac{1}{a_{1}}< 2-1<2-a_{1}$$

Induction case: Assume $n=k$, then

> $$a_{k+1}=2-\frac{1}{a_{k}}<2-a_{k}$$

To now prove that it holds for $n=k+1$, i.e.

> $$a_{k+2}=2-\frac{1}{a_{k+1}}<2-a_{k+1}$$

My question is: Am I right? If yes, how do I continue? If no, I'll be grateful if another proof can be provided! Various proofs are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: when $1/a_1<1$ then $-1/a_1>-1$. you got the inequalities wrong way.

Comment: @ Arian: I don't understand you! Kindly edit your post!

Comment: when you compare two numbers $a<b$ then $-a>-b$. For instance $4<5$ but $-4>-5$.

Comment: @ Arian: I've edited it!

Comment: @ Arian: Please, does it imply my solution is all wrong?

Comment: if $a_1>1$ then $1/a_1<1$ implies $-1/a_1>-1$. So $2-1/a_1>2-1=1$.

Comment: @ Arian: Does that mean that $a_{n+1}=2-\frac{1}{a_n}>a_n$ in general?

Answer (score 2):

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=2-\frac{1}{a_n}-a_n=\frac{2a_n-1-a_n^2}{a_n}=-\frac{(a_n-1)^2}{a_n}<0$$
since $a_n>0$ for all $n$. So your sequence is monotone decreasing.

Comment: @ Arian: Thank you very much!